Discord Bot Not Registering Slash Commands in Command Tree
I have a "Commands.py" file that hosts all the logic behind my commands and for some reason it's not registering my commands. My main.py calls my register_commands function passing in Client and in there it is supposed to register my client commands. Here is the code for that.
# Function to register commands
def register_commands(client):
    print("Starting command registration...")

    @client.tree.command(name="language", description="Select your language")
    async def language_command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        print("Language command registered")
        await _language(client, interaction)

    @client.tree.command(name="reactions", description="Set up reaction roles")
    async def reactions_command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        print("Reactions command registered")
        await _reactions(client, interaction)

    @client.tree.command(name="analyticsmessage", description="Fetch all messages from a specific user")
    async def analyticsmessage_command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        print("AnalyticsMessage command registered")
        await _analyticsmessage(client, interaction)
    
    # Command to manually sync commands
    @client.tree.command(name="sync", description="Manually sync commands")
    @app_commands.checks.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def sync_command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await client.tree.sync()
        await interaction.response.send_message("Commands synced.", ephemeral=True)
        print("Commands manually synced")

    print("Commands registration complete")

And this is my main.py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from config import load_config
from events import register_event_handlers
from commands import register_commands

# Load environment variables from .env file
load_dotenv()

# Get the necessary configurations from environment variables
TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')

# Set up intents for the bot to access guild, member, and message information
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.guilds = True
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True

# Custom bot client class
class MyClient(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.config = load_config()

    async def setup_hook(self):
        # Register commands
        print("Registering commands...")
        register_commands(self)
        # Ensure commands are registered globally initially
        await self.tree.sync(guild=None)
        print("Commands synced globally")

# Initialize the bot client
client = MyClient(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

# Register event handlers
register_event_handlers(client)

# Run the bot
client.run(TOKEN)


I have added multiple loggers and I am getting the following responses when running the bot.
Registering commands... Starting command registration... Commands registration complete Commands synced globally
And it's not going in and logging the seperate client.tree.command logging statements in there. I'm not exactly sure what's wrong but my /language commands are working. I think this MAY be a fluke because I originally had all my code in 1 file and I seperated it into multiple files to keep it modular and I think the /language command is still registered from that, because the other commands are new after the split. I also tried changing the order of the commands in the register_commands function, but that didn't change anything, /language is still the only one popping up.

I was able to fix this with following changes to my setup_hook:
    async def setup_hook(self):
    # Register commands
    register_commands(self)
    # Ensure commands are registered for each guild dynamically
    for guild_id in self.config.keys():
        guild = discord.Object(id=int(guild_id))
        await self.tree.sync(guild=guild)

My config.JSON holds the guild ID's of each server it joins and I just pass that through the setup_hook and it started syncing the commands.
